# how to deploy dockerize mern app on aws ec2 instance?

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-ec2, nginx

i dockerized my mern app (Next js, node js , mongodb) and trying to deploy it on aws ec2 instance. when i try to access my backend on port 5000 via aws public ip then it works fine when i try to access frontend then terminal stuck and if i try to reload the terminal then ssh gives error.
then i have to stop the instance and start the instance. then again backend works fine and when try to access frontend it gives error.
this is my folder structure looks like

**myecommerce folder
then it have two more folders
backend
frontend
nginx
(nginx have two files one is dockerfile and second is nginx.conf)
docker-compose.yml**

**this is how my nginx docker file looks like**

```
FROM nginx:latest


RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/*

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

**this is how my nginx.conf file looks like**

```
events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name here my aws public ip;

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

**this is my frontend folder docker file**

```
FROM node:20-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD npm run dev
```

**this is my backend folder docker file**

```
FROM node:20-alpine

RUN npm install -g nodemon


WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

**this is how my docker-compose.yml looks like**

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    image: my frontend image from docker hub
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  backend:
    image:my backend image from dockerhub
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"

  nginx:
    image: my nginx image from dockerhub
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

later i want to setup github ci cd pipelines for it and using custom domain to access the website later. i am not sure if i am using docker-compose i still need to setup pm2.
i am also posting my inbound rules i dont know why frontend is not working. guys i am beginner in aws deployment and dockerization. i am improving my skills please help me i am stuck in this from many days i saw alot of videos and watched multiple videos but not a single article or video doing what i am actually trying to do. Thanks in advance

[image]